# How to reject and push the elements to an array at a time

Tags: ruby, arrays

For Example i have an array like `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. I want add `"a", "e"` to that array. In that time how to `"a"` will get reject and how to `"e"` will push to that existing array.

Comment: what is the input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: @UriAgassi expected output is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

Comment: I bet it is: no dup in array.

Comment: Uri gave you a good answer but I suggest that in future you hold off awhile before selecting your preferred answer.  There's no rush at all. It's very common to wait a couple of hours, or more, before making a selection. A quick selection can discourage other (possibly better) answers, and for some it's a bummer to see the green checkmark come on while they are still preparing an answer.

Comment: You should edit your question to add your reply to Uri's question (The expected....). If you don't, the votes to close will probably increase. More generally, you should always clarify by editing the question, rather than trying to do so in comments. However, make sure you do not change the question by your edit. Sometimes it's wise to preface your edit with 'Edit:'. When you give an example (which is appreciated), always give the desired result.

Comment: Why down vote for that question ? Can explain any one please. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the union ([`|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-7C)) operator:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"] | ["a", "e"]
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```